# Git On Arch Crashes On Commit

Tags: archlinux

I've installed Git on Rpi Arch via Pacman. It installed fine. I was able to add my details to the config and initialise a new repo. I also had no trouble adding files to the repo.

But the moment I try to make a initial commit (in the default Nano text editor), the command line wigs' out. When I try to kill the program with ctrl + c, the terminal breaks completely (endlessly printing out a "EoF" error message), and only stops once the computer is switched off...

Anyone familiar with this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Was it nano which crash or git itself (in my opinion less probably).

Try to do some "dummy" commit e.g. inside your git repository, using `-m comment` argument, which embed commit message in commandline so that external text editor won't be called:

```
touch dummy.c 
echo "dummy" > dummy.c
git add dummy.c
git commit -m "my dummy commit"
```

Then you can check if commit was OK (e.g. `git log`). If it is, it's probably `nano` that causes problems, not `git`.

Comment: Was trying to answer my own question yesterday, but wasn't able to. To problem was not so much Nano itself, but not having it set. 'git config --global editor nano' fixed it. Thanks for the reply.